# Add a circle in the bottom of two pages

Tags: page-numbering

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % not needed in new latex versions
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,moreverb} % tableau de signe moreverb not needed
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % pagestyle
\begin{document}
cc
\newpage
cc
\end{document}
```

> I want to do the number of the two pages with cicle and as follows

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your question but `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % not needed in new latex versions` is a rather confusing comment. If your file is latin1 encoded then this _is_ needed. Conversely if it is UTF-8 encoded (as it has to be to post here) then the line is wrong in old and new versions of latex. (The actual example text here is just ascii so latin1 and utf-8 are the same so you get no error)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you but I use old version if I delete this package it does not compilate

Comment: then your file must be latin1 encoded and so that line will still be needed even with the current latex so the comment saying it is not needed is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Ti*k*Z node for this.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{%
    paper = a4paper,%
    top = 3cm,%
    bottom = 3.5cm,%
    left = 2.5cm,%
    right = 2.5cm,%
    footskip = 1.5cm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    showframe = false%
}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\tikz{\node [circle, draw = black] at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}}
}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

If you load the `shapes` library with `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` you could change `circle` by `ellipse` or even more fancy things like `star, star points = 5`.

[image: some ideas]

- `\node [rectangle, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}};`
- `\node [circle, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}};`
- `\node [ellipse, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}};`
- `\node [star, star points = 5, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}};`
- `\node [diamond, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}};`
- `\node [cloud, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}};`
- `\node [starburst, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}};`
- `\node [tape, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}};`